# Compare read string with string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am reading a string form a file and want in my js file act accordingly to string value. Here the code:

```
var text;
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xhr.open('GET', RUserDir+"jobstatus", false);
xhr.send();
text = xhr.responseText;
if(text!="Ok"){
window.alert("something went wrong. Read error: "+text);
ui.hideDialog('CARunning');
return;}
```

The test is returning true even if the text read is "Ok". Is there some kind of formatting issue?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is synchronous while your file reading process is not. You need to implement the onreadystatechange function (and check for readyState = 4)

Comment: @Baszz the `false` says otherwise... It is synchronous

Comment: Debug! What is in the `responseText`?

Comment: @epascarello I stand corrected. Missed that one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the whitespaces around the text with `.trim()` before comparing it with  "Ok"

```
text = xhr.responseText.trim();
```

Comment: @PaulRoub async is set to false at xhr.open('GET', RUserDir+"jobstatus", false);